# Error #1265 - Can't insert an empty value in a default 'none' field

Tags: mysql, datetime, null, mariadb, default-value

I am trying to make a simple INSERT through phpMyAdmin into a table with a column named 'date_end' with 'DATETIME' type value and default value set to 'none' (so if while inserting, at the INSERT the row it's empty, the field shouldn't end with a value) and when I try to insert something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tasks` 
            (`id`, `customer`, `technician`, `date_start`, `date_end`, `description`) 
    VALUES (NULL, '', '', '', '', '');
```

I get the following error: **#1265 - Truncated data for column 'date_end' on row 1**, and then the values inserted for 'data_start' and 'data_end' are '0000-00-00 00:00:00' instead of an empty field (this only happens when 'date_start' and/or 'date_end' are empty in the INSERT statement).

I have changed from Wamp to Xampp and in Wamp, this didn't happen, so I guess is something related to the mysql configuration? I am not sure.

I am using MariaDB 10.1.37 (which I think it's the problem) with PHP 7.3.0 and apache 2.4.37.

Comment: If date_end is going to be none/default, then do not pass the column in at all, or use NULL instead of an empty string.

Comment: Can a datetime hold `none`? Sounds like it'd cause an error.

Comment: @user3783243 I've done it several times. The field doesn't have 'none' value by default, but an empty value.

Comment: Remove `id` from the columns. If you're not going to populate it, omit it from the list.

Comment: The id column is Ai.

Comment: One of these modes is likely to be relevant: NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL/MariaDB date fields cannot contain empty string. By default, without SQL strict mode, they would convert them to a zero date, which would still be a date albeit invalid, and not empty string. You can set the date field to NULL, and pass NULL if the value is unknown.
[Since MariaDB version 10.2.4](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql-mode/), they have enabled SQL strict mode by default, which no longer allows empty dates to be inserted into DB. 
[Read more about SQL strict mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict)

> If strict mode is enabled, '0000-00-00' is not permitted and inserts produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as well. For INSERT IGNORE and UPDATE IGNORE, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce a warning.

Check your MariaDB SQL mode with this SQL through phpMyAdmin: `SELECT @@global.sql_mode;`
If the settings contain either `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` or `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` then strict mode is enabled.

Comment: Thank you. That''s what I was thinking. So, even updating MariaDB, I won't be able to make an empty string as a value for a DATETIME column? That's what I understood. Again, thank you!